# How to calculate ACTUAL innerWidth/innerHeight?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm writing a responsive website with bootstrap and I simply want an element that is the actual size of the screen.

Whenever I do height/width: 100%, the browser gives me a scrollbar because it works out my viewport as being the **full** size of the screen (i.e excluding the toolbar/other browser tabs/the Windows taskbar at the bottom). How do I work out the dimensions excluding these? From other answers, this is what innerWidth() and innerHeight() should do no? But it doesn't work for me... (see below)

There isn't much on the site I'm building (just a video carousel basically) and I don't want the user to have to go fullscreen (I'm gonna have a couple other features underneath the video) and they shouldn't have to scroll either.

My fullscreen size is 1920x940 and this is what is returned when I run:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("Inner Height: " + $(document).innerHeight());
    alert("Inner Width: " + $(document).innerWidth());
}
```

(And $(window) gave the same dimensions.)

Here's a screenshot of the problem:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
<div id="videoModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="listbox">
        <!--<div class="modal-header">-->
        <!--</div>-->
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->


                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item" ng-class="{active: !$index}" ng-repeat="video in videos">
                        <video id="{{video.videoId}}" controls>
                                <source src="{{video.webmUrl}}" type="video/webm"/>
                                <source src="{{video.mp4Url}}" type="video/mp4"/>
                                <!--<source src="{{video.ogvUrl}}" type="video/ogg"/>-->
                            </video>
                            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                <span class="icon-prev" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                            </a>
                            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                <span class="icon-next" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                            </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my css:

```
#videoModal {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 1050;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated, there's obviously something fundamental I'm missing here...! Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not use VH and VW in your css?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, I think using `VH` and `VW` units in your `CSS` file would be the best practice.

For example, you can do this sort of thing:

```
.element {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: Hi Andy, unfortunately that's the problem. Putting 100vh and 100vw on html and body (or my modal) reconciles as 1920px by 940px (which is the fullscreen size if toolbar/taskbar etc are included, so there's a scrollbar. It fits perfectly if I hit F11 and go fullscreen.

Comment: What is causing your scrollbar to show? What's under the video?

Comment: Nothing under the video...!

Comment: Well there must be something there in order for the scroll bar to show?

Comment: Hi Andy, I've updated the question with the html and css for that bit. Anything else I can provide to help?